# Show that a path connected space with a cover equivalent to a graph has a contractible universal cover

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm struggling with the following task:

Lets $X$ be a path connected space which has a cover homotopically equivalent to a graph. Prove that the universal cover of $X$ is contractible.

Comment: What do you know about covers of graphs? What about simply connected graphs?

Comment: @fixedp Well I know for example how to cover a graph with a graph and about the Cayley Graph construction. I have no idea how to relate any of this to contractibility though.

Comment: Good. Now you should ask yourself: what precisely are the graphs which are simply connected? Can you show that such graphs are contractible?

Comment: @fixedp I suppose simply connected graphs are graphs without loops? It seems pretty intuitive that you should be able to contract such a graph to its basepoint then? Is that it?

Comment: You've got it. Graphs without loops (i.e. circuits) are trees, and it is easy to contract connected trees to any basepoint. You still have to prove these two statements though, but you have the general idea.